# How to add value to the dictionary by checking the list and original dictionary python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

I have one list which contains the ID from 1 to 1500. the list is looked like this

totalID=['1','2','3',.......'1499','1500']

in the dictionary, some of the ID is assigned with score from (-1 to 4)

I would like to add the rest of IDs (totalID- dictionaryID) which is not appeared in the dictionary with the score of '5' !

for example :

```
Q216 ..............   {'1': ['156'], '-1': ['506']}
```

will  the new value is

```
{'1': ['156'], '-1': ['506'],
'5':['1','2','3','4','5',....'155','157'..'505','507','508',..'1500']}
```

how to edit the dictionary according to the  totalID and originalDICT???

```
 originalDICT={'Q216': {'1': ['156'], '-1': ['506']}, 'Q217': {'1': ['666', '667', '1395'], '3': ['668', '670', '1204', '1300', '37', '559', '630', '1107', '1213'], '2': ['1258', '1394'], '-1': ['1191'], '4': ['1391']}, 'Q214': {'3': ['833', '1361', '1362', '1363'], '-1': ['1294']}, 'Q215': {'-1': ['535'], '4': ['37', '35']}, 'Q212': {'3': ['885', '887', '886', '890', '769', '891', '1173', '843'], '2': ['888', '889', '1178'], '-1': ['1146'], '4': ['841', '1176', '1177']} }

for key, value in originalDICT.iteritems():
    print key,"..............  ", value

Q216 ..............   {'1': ['156'], '-1': ['506']}
Q217 ..............   {'1': ['666', '667', '1395'], '3': ['668', '670', '1204', '1300', '37', '559', '630', '1107', '1213'], '2': ['1258', '1394'], '-1': ['1191'], '4': ['1391']}
Q214 ..............   {'3': ['833', '1361', '1362', '1363'], '-1': ['1294']}
Q215 ..............   {'-1': ['535'], '4': ['37', '35']}
Q212 ..............   {'3': ['885', '887', '886', '890', '769', '891', '1173', '843'], '2': ['888', '889', '1178'], '-1': ['1146'], '4': ['841', '1176', '1177']}
```

how to update the dictionary??

Comment: In the question you have mentioned *"I would like to add the rest of IDs (totalID- dictionaryID) which is not appeared in the dictionary"* but int the sample example `1` is still present even though it is a key in dictionary? Please can you be precise and clear regarding what you want

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri  the '1':['156']... the'1' means the score is 1, so it means that ID=1 is not appeared in the dictionary.

Comment: I would strongly advise to set IDs to int and use as dictionary keys.

Answer (score 1):

The first step here is to find all the ID's that are already present in the dictionary. Let's use a set comprehension:

```
known_ids = {item for sublist in original_dict.values() for item in sublist}
```

Next, let's update the dictionary with all the ID's not in `known_ids`:

```
original_dict['5'] = [id for id in total_id if id not in known_ids]
```

If you want a new dictionary and want to leave `original_dict` intact, try this:

```
import copy
new_dict = copy.deepcopy(original_dict)  # use deepcopy because you have mutable containers inside the dict
new_dict['5'] = [id for id in total_id if id not in known_ids]
```

If there might be some things already assigned to '5', try this instead:

```
original_dict['5'].extend(id for id in total_id if id not in known_ids)
```

Notice that I've changed from a list comprehension to a generator expression, since we won't need the created values more than once.

EDIT: Based on a (now, apparently deleted comment), you can use set operations if `total_id` is a set instead of a list.

```
total_id = set(total_id)
original_dict['5'] = list(total_id - known_ids)
# or
original_dict['5'].extend(total_id - known_ids)
```

Depending on several factors, this might or might not be faster than the `in` construction in the list comprehension.

EDIT 2: Given the actual formatting of the OP's `originalDICT`, we need to do a bit more faffing about:

```
known_ids = {key: {item for sublist in value.values() for item in sublist} for key, value in originalDICT.items()}
for key, known_id_set in known_ids.items():
    originalDICT[key]['5'] = [id for id in total_id if id not in known_ids]
    # or, if '5' is already populated
    originalDICT[key]['5'].extend(id for id in total_id if id not in known_ids]
    # or, if total_id is a set
    originalDICT[key]['5'] = list(total_id - known_id_set)
```

Because we're only updating a portion of the outermost dictionary this time, this is more difficult (impossible? I haven't thought too hard about it) to make a dictionary comprehension. The explicit for loop here is probably the clearer solution.

Comment: You make a good point! I started out committed to the set but kinda petered out there. I was going with the OP's use of list for `total_id`, which wouldn't have `difference` unfortunately. `total_id = set(total_id)` might be helpful to use, however.

Comment: known_ids=set(['1', '3', '2', '-1', '4'])  I think the known_ids is wrong, what you get is the score , not the ID.  the known_ids should be ['156'], ['506'] for Q216, and so on..

Comment: `d = {'1': ['156'], '-1': ['506']}; known_ids = {item for sublist in d.values() for item in sublist}; assert known_ids == {'506', '156'}` works for me in both Python 2 and 3. Did I incorrectly interpret how your input dictionary is formatted?

Comment: Oh! I see the issue. Updated answer incoming.

Answer (score -2):

One liner!

```
original_dict[5] = [i+1 for i in range(1500) if i not in original_dict]
```

Comment: That's not right. Because inside the dicts are arrays. Wenn you try 12 in {1:[112,12]} it returns false